# U.S resident traveling to Ghana

Tags: visas, volunteering, ghana

I was born in Colombia and I live in the U.S (permanent resident). I am 22. I will be going to Ghana in a couple of months to volunteer with a non-profit organization for two weeks and I need to know what the requirements are for me to travel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a Visa and a [yellow card](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carte_Jaune) showing you've been immunized against yellow fever. Any pharmacy should be able to provide you with the yellow cards but you'll need to ask. The [CDC recommends](http://wwwnc.cdc.gov/travel/destinations/traveler/none/ghana) additional vaccinations against Hepatitis A, Malaria and Typhoid. More info:

http://www.ghanaembassy.org/index.php?page=visas